# BRAutoSetup quit unexpectedly - when adding the CUPS printer driver

Tags: macos, report, device, printers, network-printers

During the installation of a new Brother printer on my Mac, I had an unpleasant alert window, that BRAutoSetup quit unexpectedly and was unable to add a printer in my network.
Like these ones:

[image: BrAutoSetup alert window]

[image: Error occured while trying to add selected device]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to install the newest drivers from main apple website for the related printer manufacturer, although they should be already available in the MacOS, they weren't, so if you will encounter the same problem, give it a try.

[Apple Support Download Page](http://%22BRAutoSetup%20quit%20unexpectedly%22%20when%20adding%20the%20CUPS%20printer%20driver)

I am posting here on SO just for the sake of others who will try to google it (as of now there's a lot of scam websites with "solution" or just ones that did not help me).

---

EDIT 2022

Since there was some errors and links were changed and are down now, make sure to go to Brother's website and download *updated* CUPS drivers from your device page.
ie: [hl1210w](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl1210w_eu_as)

[Official Brother support page](https://support.brother.com) -> Choose language -> Product search -> Type in your product -> Downloads

Most should have updated drivers now (and pages have refreshed links) since new MacOs rollout.

Comment: Unfortunately that link is completely broken: "http://%22BRAutoSetup%20quit%20unexpectedly%22%20when%20adding%20the%20CUPS%20printer%20driver".

Comment: Updated with newest links and referring to Brother support page (with updated drivers)